# Why is my object not updated in the view in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have SignalR working in my application:

```
app.run(['SignalRService', function (SignalRService) {}]);
```

SignalRService:

```
app.service("SignalRService",  ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    var masterdataChangerHub = $.connection.progressHub;

    if (masterdataChangerHub != undefined) {
        masterdataChangerHub.client.updateProgress = function (progress) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('progressChanged', progress);
        }

        masterdataChangerHub.client.completed = function (result) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('taskCompleted', result);
        }
    }

    $.connection.hub.start();
}]);
```

As you can see I throw an event when a SignalR method gets invoked. This all works fine. However, on 1 directive, my data won't get updated. Here's the code:

```
app.directive('certificateDetails', ['CertificateService', 'TradeDaysService', 'DateFactory', function (CertificateService, TradeDaysService, DateFactory) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/Certificate/Details',
        scope: {
            certificateId: '=',
            visible: '=',
            certificate: '=',
            certificateSaved: '&'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            scope.certificateFormVisible = false;
            scope.showCancelDialog = false;
            scope.splitCertificateFormVisible = false;
            scope.partialPayoutFormVisible = false;

            scope.$on("taskCompleted", function (evt, response) {
                console.log(response);

                    CertificateService.getCertificateById(scope.certificate.Id).then(function (response) {
                        scope.certificate = response;
                    });

            });

            scope.$watch('visible', function (newVal) {
                if (newVal === true) {
                    scope.showButtonBar = attributes.showButtonBar || true;

                    if (scope.certificateId) {
                        getCertificateById();
                    }
                }
            });

            function getCertificateById() {
                CertificateService.getCertificateById(scope.certificateId).then(function (response) {
                    scope.certificate = response;
                });
            };
        }
    }
}]);
```

The weird thing is, when I have my console open (I use Chrome) on the network tab, I can see that the directive makes a request to the right URL with the right parameters. Also, when the console is open, my data is updated in the view. However, and this is the strange part, when I close the console, nothing happens! It doesn't update the view..

I have also tried to put the code inside the `taskCompleted` event in a `$timeout` but that doesn't work either.

Could someone explain why this happens and how to solve this problem?

EDIT I

This is how the getCertificateById looks like in my CertificateService

```
this.getCertificateById = function (id) {
    var promise = $http.post('/Certificate/GetById?id=' + id).then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
    });

    return promise;
};
```

Comment: Could we see `CertificateService`? Are you using `$http` in it? I'm asking because `getCertificateById` looks to be doing an asynchronous request, right? And if nothing is doing a `$scope.$apply` in it setting `scope.certificate` won't be `$apply`ed. Any Angular service (like `$http`) _will_ `$apply` it, but something like a `jQuery.ajax` won't.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv See my updated post. I think it is `$apply`ed because when having the console open, the view is updated...

Comment: You need to either watch a service value or listen for rootscope emit a value update event then update directive scope value manually

Answer (score 2):

Handling `SignalR` events will execute out of the Angular context.  You will need to `$apply` in order to force digest for these to work.  I'd try to call `$apply` on `$rootScope` after the `$broadcast`:

```
var masterdataChangerHub = $.connection.progressHub;

if (masterdataChangerHub != undefined) {
    masterdataChangerHub.client.updateProgress = function (progress) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('progressChanged', progress);
        $rootScope.$apply();
    }

    masterdataChangerHub.client.completed = function (result) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('taskCompleted', result);
        $rootScope.$apply();
    }
}
```

If this works then the issue definitely a binding issue between SignalR and Angular.  Depending on what browser plugins you have installed, having the console open could trigger a digest for you.

On the sample listeners for [this project (that binds SignalR and Angular)](https://github.com/JustMaier/angular-signalr-hub), you can see that a `$rootScope.$apply()` is needed after handling on the client side:

```
//client side methods
listeners:{
    'lockEmployee': function (id) {
        var employee = find(id);
        employee.Locked = true;
        $rootScope.$apply();
    },
    'unlockEmployee': function (id) {
        var employee = find(id);
        employee.Locked = false;
        $rootScope.$apply();
    }
}
```

So, I'd assume that you would need to do the same.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. I still have the same situation. I have added `$rootScope.apply();` as you suggested, but still my view isn't updated...